# Как можно реализовать анимацию волны по нижней границы инпута?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, layout

Как можно реализовать анимацию волны по нижней границы инпута?
Мне нужно чтобы при клике на инпут ввода текста, по его нижней границе "прошла волна".

Вот как у на этом сайте:
https://www.cloudmill.ru/contacts/

Меня интересует самый простой, лаконичный способ реализовать это.

Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот максимально упрощенный способ сделать это так, как в вашем примере:

```css
.form {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.input-field {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #000;
}

.graphic {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ff6f61;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: transform 1s, stroke 1s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0.25, 0.5, 1);
}

.input-field:focus ~ .graphic {
    stroke: #ff6f61;
    transform: translate3d(-66.6%, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input class="input-field" id="name" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="">
  <svg class="graphic" width="300%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 60" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0,56.5c0,0,298.666,0,399.333,0C448.336,56.5,513.994,46,597,46c77.327,0,135,10.5,200.999,10.5c95.996,0,402.001,0,402.001,0"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```